# Calculate year based on combination of smallint and datetime2(7)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I hope I can explain this correctly....

I have this table:

```
[InspectionSchedule] [smallint] NULL,
[NeedsAssesment] [smallint] NULL,
[DateLastInspected] [datetime2](7) NULL,
```

and let's say `DateLastInspected` is `2010-01-01 00:00:00.0000000` globally.

`InspectionSchedule` has values that are 1, 5, or 10 and represents so many years when an asset must be inspected.

I'm hoping for help with a simple query that will take `DateLastInspected`, add the value of `InspectionSchedule` to it, and return a Year, n years in the future. I know this is done with a CAST operator, but I get lost from there.

Here's where it gets tricky: Instead of a date n years in the future, we just need a year, N years in the future, based on Fiscal Year (Oct 1). For example, if an asset was inspected on `2010-07-30 00:00:00.0000000`, which is FY 09, and was on a 5-year inspection cycle, then this "math" would return the next inspection year as "2014". I hope this make sense. I'm sure this is a simple matter of joining a bunch of CASTS and DATEPARTS, but I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use such code:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -9, DATEADD(YEAR, [InspectionSchedule], [DateLastInspected])))
```

It does 3 things:

1. Adds number of years of inspection schedule to date last inspected. We get the date of next inspection.
2. Remove 9 months from this date so you transform from fiscal year to actual year
3. Take only the year value

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DATEADD()` to add the `InspectionSchedule` to `DateLastInspected`, then use the `YEAR()` function to grab the year. Something along these lines:

```
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,InspectionSchedule,DateLastInspected))
```

Now, determining whether or not `DateLastInspected` belongs to what fiscal year is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SQL DATEADD(datepart,number,date)` function: pertinent to your case, `DATEADD(year,number,date)`. Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will give you what you are looking for:

```
select datepart(yyyy, dateadd(yy, InspectionSchedule, DateLastInspected))
from <YourTableName>
```

EDIT: if you want the result to be the Fiscal Year of the next inspection, you will want to add a test for if the *LAST* inspection date was before or after 01-Oct, and add 1 to the calendar year to get your fiscal year, like this:

```
select datepart(yyyy, dateadd(yy, InspectionSchedule, DateLastInspected)) + 
    case when datepart(MM, DateLastInspected) >= 10 then 1 else 0 end
from <YourTableName>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be more elegant...

```
IF (UPDATE(DateLastInspected) OR UPDATE (InspectionSchedule))
   BEGIN
UPDATE [table] SET NeedsAssesment = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, +3, DateLastInspected))+     InspectionSchedule
   END
```

I would use a trigger, but that's just me. Good luck tpcolson